# What's the NEET's verb form in English?

Tags: phrase-request

The noun NEET is called 啃老 in Chinese. Which means an adult keep getting money from the parents with no job.

There's a good description at Wikipedia.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEET

The question is how to use this word in Verb? or Are there any verbs that have same meaning?

For example:

let the verb be X,

> You have to stop X-ing, and find a job.
>
> X-ing can't solve anything.

Comment: NEET isn't a verb.

Comment: I know it's a noun, so I posted this question.

Comment: The Brits often say here: You have to stop mucking about.

Comment: NEET is not a mainstream 'word'; for one thing, it is written in all-capitals. Likewise made-up terms like DINK (of a couple - Dual Income, No Kids), another socio-economic acronym beloved of lazy journalists.

Comment: Lambie, we sometimes use a word that sounds like 'mucking'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Of course, but I was trying to avoid that. There is also messing about. Stop messing about. These expressions might be used by AmE speakers in the know, so to speak, but are not known by people in general in the states.

Comment: Arsing about is good too.

Comment: @Lambie - "Stop messing about" too much of a reminder of Kenneth Williams for many Brits.

Comment: @Lambie Can the word "About" be omitted?

Comment: Absolutely not: messing about/around, mucking about, screwing around (also with f***), hanging about or around, arsing about, need their prepositions. And I am plenty sure I have not exhausted every single way of saying these things that mean: to not be doing anything or taking things seriously.

Comment: Actually, Brits sometimes say [no messing](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/and-no-messing) to convey the same meaning as e.g. 'no messing around', 'no fooling around', 'no unnecessary time wasting', etc, or to emphasise that you want something done. "Bradford City: No messing in Bowyer's training plans" - Bradford Argus

Comment: I don't think nouns such as this have a verb form. What is the verb form of "bird"? Is it "fly"? Is it "nest"? Is it "peck"? How does the question even make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can say 'to sponge from someone' which would suit your explanation of 'neet'.

You have to stop sponging and find a job.

Does that answer your question.

Answer (score 4):

The direct answer to your question is

- You have to stop **being a NEET**, and find a job.
- **Being a NEET** can't solve anything.

But as other answers have said, NEET is not something most people would understand; it's a pretty specialised word from the UK newspaper's political pages.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of living off someone else's money is often referred to in the US as "bumming" or "freeloading" both of which would be usable in your example sentences.  Neither has the same "shut-in" connotation that NEET does in Japanese pop culture though (which is the only place I've seen used despite it's origins).

Answer (score 1):

The acronym NEET is a rather specialised word, whose meaning is changing.

It was originally used by the government in the UK as a way of measuring school performance.  A good school would get its students into university, job or training after they finish, so the government measured the number of people who were Not in Education Employment or Training 6 months after leaving school.

It was originally used like an adjective:

> The school has a low number of people who are NEET at six months.

It then became adapted to be used as a noun.

> The school has a low number of NEETs at six months.

It then picked up a perjoritive sense, especially in Asia. It shifted in meaning from "people who were unable to find a job" to "people who chose not to look for a job".  This is the sense that you have learnt. But be careful, since this meaning of NEET is not widely used outside of Asia. In Britain NEET is still mostly a technical word used by school managers. I don't think the word is used much in American English at all.

> I'm worried that Hitoshi will become a NEET. All he does is sit in his room and play video games.

Now, the question that you ask "what is verb for NEET" doesn't make much sense.  For example, what is the verb for "apple" or the verb for "secretary". In general there isn't a way to change a noun "X" to a verb that means "being an X".

Comment: Stop *NEETing* about/around? No? I'd say you'd know exactly what I mean provided you knew what *NEET* means in the first place.